# Does anyone say Tefillas Haderech when traveling by foot?

Tags: halacha, blessing, tefilat-haderech

**LOOKING FOR A *MA'ASEH RAV*:**

As far as I know, the obligation to say [Tefillas Haderech](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/tefilat-haderekh-the-travelers-prayer/) is applicable to all modes of travel, whether by foot or with a vehicle of any kind.

Does anyone know of any Rav/posek/Halachic authority (or anyone else halachically reliable) who has said Tefillas Haderech while traveling by foot?

Comment: I am confused by this question,why would you want a maaseh Rav when you have halacha ,such as MB 110:30,its all dependent on distance and safety

Comment: @sam You are not "confused", there is no confusion involved in your question. You just are wondering why I would want it. I'll explain. When there is a halacha which I have never heard anyone actively doing, I begin to wonder whether I'm missing some knowledge regarding that halacha. I therefore want to first inquire whether there is any record of this halacha being activly kept.

Comment: What other methods were there 2000 years ago

Comment: @DoubleAA Camels, donkeys, horses & wagons...

Comment: Rav Sheshet says you can say it while walking. Does he count?

Comment: @DoubleAA If course R' Sheshet Counts! but that is not what I was looking for. I clearly stated in my question than I already know that TH is said even when walking, but I'm looking for a MA'ASEH RAV, which the statement of R' sheshet does not provide.

Comment: Why are you looking for a Ma’aseh Rav, when you have the Gemara? Plus, the Shulchan Aruch (OC 110:4) implies this as well - ואם אפשר יעמד מלילך כשיאמרנה ואם היה רוכב א״צ.

Comment: "Nuance" - Are you seeking a specific "current" Rav who did it, himself, or is a ruling from a contemporary rav a good enough answer? Though, I'd be somewhat surprised of one issuing such a ruling if he wouldn't follow this, himself, but, it's possible.

Comment: @DonielF <<Why are you looking for a Ma’aseh Rav,>> See my response to sam. - ok I'll repeat. When there is a halacha which I have never heard anyone actively doing, I begin to wonder whether I'm missing some knowledge regarding that halacha. I therefore want to first inquire whether there is any record of this halacha being actively kept

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore Okay, I just missed that comment. I’m not sure that the fact nobody keeps it anymore is symptomatic of anything other than nobody takes a walk a Parsa outside the city to travel - we have cars, planes, and trains for that. I don’t think it’s an issue of not understanding the Halacha so much as it doesn’t really apply anymore. Not saying it’s a bad question the way you’ve phrased it, just that that seems to be the main issue.

Comment: @DonielF <<"nobody takes a walk a Parsa outside the city to travel" >>, well, I'll ask you this. Is the halacha of T'chum shabbos applicable today? There are plenty of rural areas where the halachos of T'chum shabbos exist. (in the countryside, In moshavim or kibutzim where the roads between villages is not populated.)  - The distance of T'chum Shabbos is 1 mil= .598 miles just over 1/2 mile.  - Tfilas Haderech 1 parsah= is 4 mil= 2.392 miles just over 2 miles, not a great distance at all for taking a walk. So I wouldn't say that people don't walk a parsah.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore I never said people don’t walk a parsa. I said people don’t typically walk a parsa as a form of travel between cities.

Comment: @DonielF Remember T'chum shabbos is also only applicable between cities.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore Nowadays T’chum Shabbos, as you said, is only really applicable to someone out in the middle of nowhere for Shabbos. How do you think they got there? Probably by car.

Answer (score 1):

This [dinonline.org](http://dinonline.org/2012/05/31/halacha-talk-tefilas-haderech/) article implies more "contemporary" rabbanim, namely Rav Shlomo Auerbach and Chazon Ish, who indicate that Tefillat Haderech should be recited even when travelling on foot, but without a bracha if you are travelling in most cities. However, if you are walking through a known dangerous area (I guess certain areas of New York City that are considered high crime areas would qualify), then you should recite with a bracha. I'm excerpting some parts:

> It does not matter whether one travels by foot, automobile, boat,
>   train or airplane. As long as the trip consists of the minimum
>   distance, tefilas haderech is recited. (Mishnah Berurah 110:30, Sefer
>   Ishei Yisrael chap. 50, footnote 5, Sefer Tefilah K’Hilchasah 27:27,
>   Shu”t Be’er Moshe vol. VII chap. 114:1)
>
> In earlier generations intercity roads passed through desolate and
>   totally unpopulated areas. Therefore, the danger of highwaymen and
>   wild animals was very prevalent. It is for this reason that these two
>   dangers are specifically mentioned in the text of tefilas haderech.
>
> The question is, however, what is the status of our roadways? Very
>   often, even intercity roads traverse populated areas, thus minimizing
>   the original types of dangers mentioned in tefilas haderech. Does one
>   recite tefilas haderech if he travels on such a road?
>
> The crux of the issue is: Did Chazal institute tefilas haderech only
>   because of those specifically mentioned dangers, or was it instituted
>   for other types of danger as well?
>
> This is debated by contemporary poskim. The Chazon Ish zt”l maintains
>   that all types of dangers were included and since automobile travel is
>   dangerous, one recites tefilas haderech even if traveling intercity in
>   built up areas. HaRav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach zt”l, however, holds that
>   tefilas haderech was instituted only for the stated types of danger.
>   Hence on many of our roads, tefilas haderech is said without the
>   concluding bracha.
>
> Of course, if the area of travel is known to be a dangerous place,
>   tefilas haderech is recited with the concluding bracha, as we
>   previously mentioned. (Sefer Ishei Yisrael chap. 50, footnote 24)

The term "travel" doesn't seem to be restricted to just by automobile. I'd be surprised if Chazon Ish and Rav Auerbach would nullify with Mishna Berurah and others have stated.

Comment: Thank you very much for the plethora of information on the subject. Still I was asking more for an incident than for a halachic source. But for now, I'll be satisfied with what you sent. Thanx again.